# How to find where android service is created from?

Tags: android

I am wondering how to find where an android service is created from? For example, I have two different activities and create some buttons. When a user clicks a button, it will start the service. But how can I check if that service is created from the activity that I expected?

The service class:

```
public class BluetoothService extends Service {
   ...
}
```

The activity class:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   /** This is a button */
   public void createBluetoothService(View view) {
      Intent in = new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
      startService(in);
   }

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Please let me know if the question is not cleared.

Comment: You can put some data to intent as extras

Comment: You can `Log` some data, you can `Debug` and put a `breakpoint` on the `Service`, you can send `extras` as @KonradKrakowiak said and so on

Comment: I just saw another thread saying "onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)" will do the trick. How exactly I can use that to detect the BluetoothService is created from SettingsActivity? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, you mean put some extra data in the intent. I think that should work too. Let me try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @KonradKrakowiak suggestion, I am just writing an answer to my own question. Hope this will help the others.

The activity class:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  /** This is a button */
  public void createBluetoothService(View view) {
     Intent in = new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
     in.putExtra("class", "SettingsActivity");
     startService(in);
  }

}
```

The service class:

```
public class BluetoothService extends Service {

   ...

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
      String check = bundle.getString("class");

      if (check.equals("SettingsActivity")) {
         // do something
      }

      return START_STICKY;
   }

}
```

This seems working great for me. Thanks for the tips.